# What is "platformAttrExtractor" in Android Task Execution?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, profiler

I profile my build follwings [instruction](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/optimize-your-build.html#profile) in Android:

```
gradlew --profile --recompile-scripts --offline --rerun-tasks assembleFlavorDebug
```

I found "UI:platformAttrExtractor" takes a long time, please see the screenshot.

[image: Profile Build]

I don't understand what "platformAttrExtractor" is and how can I remove it to save build time?

Comment: As from the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/actions/AttrExtractor.kt), the goal of `platformAttrExtractor` is to: `Extract attr IDs from a jar file and puts it in a R.txt`. Not sure why it takes time though...

Answer (score 0):

I have the sample "problem". What I noticed is that by specifying the `--offline` command line option for gradle, build time (and specifically the time taken by the platformAttrExtractor) task is reduced considerably