# What is the platformAttrExtractor gradle task and why is it slow?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an android solution that has a long build process.  I did a gradle profile and found that the "platformAttrExtractor" task execution is taking exceedingly long(6+ minutes)   I was wondering what this task was, as I cannot find a shred of information about it online, and how I can cut down its runtime.

Comment: seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660949/what-is-platformattrextractor-in-android-task-execution) (which doesn't have a real answer either)